# Access to downloaded video files in Swift, iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make an app that allows users to download videos to play offline, like downloading some videos for offline viewing in Netflix.

I am using Firebase as a server for the videos. Here comes the action for a download button:

```
@IBAction func btnDL(_ sender: Any) {

    self.dlBtnOutlet.isEnabled = false
    //Firebase
    let storage = Storage.storage()
    let videoRef = storage.reference(forURL: "gs://videowcoredata.appspot.com/Some video file.mp4")

    //Local file system
    let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let localURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("movie.mp4")

    // Download to the local filesystem
    let downloadTask = videoRef.write(toFile: localURL) { (URL, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("Uh-oh, an error occurred!")
            print(error)
        } else {
            print("Local file URL is returned")
            self.genericURL = String(localURL.path)
            print(localURL.path)

            //Save the link to CoreData
            let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
            let myUrl = MyFiles(context: context)
            myUrl.fileURL = self.genericURL
            (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
```

I am using CoreData just for the persistence of the downloaded file link. Saving the links to an array, and returning the last member of the array as the downloaded link. I am trying to play the file in a new AVPlayerViewController, with the help of prepare for segue.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    // Fetch CoreData
    let destination = segue.destination as! AVPlayerViewController
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    do {
        urlList = try context.fetch(MyFiles.fetchRequest())
    }
    catch {
        print("Oops we have an error!)")
    }

    self.genericURL = (urlList.last?.fileURL)!

    destination.player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: self.genericURL))
}
```

I define two variables in the beginning of the code to access later:

```
var urlList : [MyFiles] = []

var genericURL = ""
```

So, my questions are:

1. I can manage to download the file, locate the downloaded file and save its path to CoreData for persistence. I can play the local video from the local file with the code above, but when I restart the simulator I no longer have access to the file. I need to download again, which is the thing I am trying to avoid. What can be the reason for this?
2. I wish to do this without using CoreData, since it is about File handling. But I don't have adequate resources to learn Filemanager. I simply want to protect my videos (I don't want that user syncs them) and I want my users to have offline access if they wish, but I don't want to include the videos in the Bundle. What would be the best way for this?

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: What do you mean when you say you "no longer have access to the file" after restarting?  How are you you trying to look up the local file?

Comment: When I restart the simulator and try to play the local video file (which was downloaded in the previous session) AV Player does not play it with a symbol of a broken media icon in the middle of the screen. When I download again, it can play.

Comment: Are you displaying a list of files somewhere that you choose from?  Are you sure it's retrieving the correct file URL from core data?  Files don't just get deleted between sessions, so I suspect that you either aren't storing or aren't reading the file URL correctly.

Comment: That's possible. But as far as I checked the file URL is correct. I don't know if it changes every time a new session starts and the previous URL is deleted.